# Website with nested tables structure: How to remove padding and margin only for the main structure and not for a table inside?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, netsuite, zurb-foundation-5, nested-table

I am working on a website that uses tables for the structure and it is impossible to have access to them and replace then with divs. I have looked at using jquery to remove and replace these tables but for now it would be the last solution...if it was even possible

They come with a default styling that is also not accessible (with padding and margin)

I also use foundation 5 for this project on Netsuite so i am overwriting 2 style sheets.

I am using this CSS to strip the margin and padding from the table that comes with the foundation.css

```
   table, tr, td, table, table tr.even, table tr.alt, table tr:nth-of-type(even), table, table tr.odd, table tr.alt, table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

It basically does a good job but i do need to get more specific because the shopping cart uses also tables and it strips all margins and padding and it is impossible to add them afterwards as it won't take them.

Here is the website main body structure that i would need to remove the margin and padding but i would like it to stop at the last table structure to allow me to style the content inside that would use tables.

Thanks for your helps! I hope i was clear enough ;)

```
<div id='div__body' style="margin: 0px;  margin-top: 3px;">
    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' id='__enclosingtable'>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr class='portletHandle' id='handle_welcomeMainPortlet' >
                        <td width='100%' height=0 align='left' valign='top'>
                            <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width=0 height=0 align='left' valign='top' style='display:none'>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>


<!-- MAIN CONTENT WITH DIVS OR TABLES  GOES HERE -->



                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if it can help you:

```
table{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

table  table{
    border-color:red;
     padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AliAdravi/t5k7sa0q/

Answer (score 0):

Your tr has an ID attached to it `<tr class='portletHandle' id='handle_welcomeMainPortlet'>`, you can target that and the table nested under it. Ideally you would have a table cell `<td>` inside your row like this:

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
   <tr>
      <td width=0 height=0 align='left' valign='top' style='display:none'>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <div><!-- MAIN CONTENT WITH DIVS GOES HERE --></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can target that like this:

```
   #handle_welcomeMainPortlet table tr td div {
       css code goes here...
    }
```

Here's a fiddle example for your review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/hrx0vwrf/2/

Comment: If i add a table inside and set the margin and padding to 0 to  #handle_welcomeMainPortlet table tr td - the table inside inherit now of the set margin and padding 0 - This is the problem, i do not want the padding and margin to apply to a table inside.

Comment: You can target that specifically by `#id table table`, here's the revised fiddle for your review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/hrx0vwrf/3/

Comment: I tweaked your code, it was almost working until i added padding to the content in green and then the previous table took the padding as well. I am looking for striping the structure margin and padding BUT allow padding and margin for the element inside (will be a table) that will not also affect the structure padding and margin as i want it to be 0.

Comment: Perhaps you're still using `padding: 0px !important` and `margin: 0 !important;`, that's the only thing I can see that would be causing it. Take that out and it should work as expected. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/hrx0vwrf/4/ for you to review.

Comment: That's because the body has a default margin of 8px;, that's why the width of the table didn't stretch all the way like the `div`. Use `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` to reset it and add `border-spacing: 0;` to the table. The table and div now match. Here's your revised fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/hrx0vwrf/6/